# In C#, what is the simplest way to calculate "trend" given a current and previous status?

Tags: c#

I have a variable to show RAG Status (Red, Amber, Green) on a project

```
var previousStatus = "R"
var currentStatus = "A"
```

and i am trying to calculate "Trend" so sometihng like

```
  var trend = CalculateTrend(previous, current)
```

I am trying to find a more elegant solution than

```
            if (prev == current)
            return "Stable";
         if (prev == "R" && (current == "G" ||current == "A"))
              return "Improving";
         if (prev == "G" && (current == "R" ||current == "A"))
              return "Declining";
        if (prev == "A" && current == "G")
            return "Improving";
        if (prev == "A" && current == "R")
            return "Declining";
```

any suggestion on a "cleaner" solution.

Comment: If they were defined as an enumeration (as they ought to be constants anyway), then you could just compare their values as integers.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: use enums. That would help a lot.

Comment: it's a lot easier to use numbers rather than arbitrary values... then you can actually use math to determine statistics like average, changes over time, etc.  1 = G, 2 = A, 3 = R or whatever.

Comment: use an enum and then check if the current is <, = or > the previous

Comment: Wow, within 60 seconds many of us had the same idea...

Comment: @clcto This question would need a bit of more context to be well-received on CR. This code feels a bit stripped down. Unlike SO, CR wants *more* context, not code that has been stripped down.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd That won't work.  String comparing "A" to either "R" or "G" would yield the same result, and they are at opposite ends of the scale here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `enum` with an integer value for each status.

```
public enum Status
{
    Red = 1,
    Amber = 2,
    Green = 3           
}
```

Then use `int.CompareTo` method.

```
switch(previous.CompareTo(current))
{
    case -1:
        return "Improving";

    case 0:
        return "Stable";

    case 1:
        return "Declining";
}
```

Comment: You don't need those `break;` statements since they are proceeded by `return` statements.

Comment: Good point.  I'm just in the habit of always putting them.  Typically I don't do multiple returns inside a `switch` like that.  I would typically set a variable to that value, then return the variable outside of the `switch`.

Comment: Actually its more than just not needing them, it will generate a compiler warning about unreachable code.

Comment: I removed the `break` from each `case`, since it apparently REALLY bothers you guys.  Haha.

Comment: Code smell burns the retinas of us programmers!

Comment: Wrong term, but I think you get what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Use a numeric system.  Rate the values with equivalent numeric values.  Then you can use math.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the if statements you can create a simple lookup dictionary:

```
private static string GetTrend(string prev, string cur)
{
    var trends = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
    {
        {"Stable",    new[] {"AA", "RR", "GG"}},
        {"Improving", new[] {"RG", "RA", "AG"}},
        {"Declining", new[] {"GA", "GR", "AR"}},
    };

    return trends.Single(x => x.Value.Contains(prev + cur)).Key;
}
```

Comment: It's a creative solution, I'll give you that.  But this is the type of code that will make a maintenance programmer curse your name in the future if it is not thoroughly commented.